# Over 400 errors when using Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am working on some coursework and the code works perfectly fine on the university system but when I transfer the exact same code to my own PC, I get over 400 error messages. These consist of:

- Cannot open source file "name.h"
- The global scope has no "name"
- identifier "name" is undefined
- explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)
- A full list is here `https://pastebin.com/CRJd7hAp`

I get these errors on all of my code, even something as simple as a Hello World program

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout << "Hello world!  " << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

I am at a loss as for what to do.

Comment: This simple Hello World should definitely compile with Visual Studio. My best guess would be that your Visual Studio installation is somehow broken. I would suggest to uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio and then make sure you can compile your simple hello world example before doing anything else.

Comment: Giving error messages for one program and the code for another isn't all that useful. Which version of Visual Studio are you using? If I recall correctly some don't install C++ by default.

Comment: Visual Studio Version 15.9.1

Comment: I think your compiler is broken in that it can't find the standard library. Perhaps the selected SDK is no longer installed. With that said I am confused with the errors list. I don't think it matches the code that is in the question.

Comment: The code in the question isn't the code for the errors but I am getting the same errors no matter what code is used

Comment: ***I am at a loss as for what to do*** Check your project settings for SDK version. Make sure the selected SDK is actually installed.

Comment: The first error is because you use the system() function, but have not included any header that declares it. You need to add `#include <cstdlib>` for that.
The other errors are very odd, especially because they're being reported in system headers.

Comment: Also: Run VIsual Studio Installer and update to 15.9.2 (latest version as of this writing). If the issue persists, run VIsual Studio Installer again and hit the Modify button, then select Individual Components. Then ensure that the install C++ tools are the most recent ones ("VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16 latest v141 tools") and that a recent Windows SDK is installed ("Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17763.0)" is the latest, and you shouldn't need any others installed). (The Windows SDK shouldn't even be strictly needed for a Hello World like that.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Visual Studio and set the SDK from 8.1 to the newest release. Everything is working fine now. Thank you