# Visual Studio isn’t running a Hello World script - even the one that it included in the build

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I’ve began to use Visual Studio, and I’m trying to make a simple hello world script. However, when i try to run the hello world script that they included, nothing shows up - except for 437 errors, all along the lines of:
`cannot open source file “ctype.h”`
I assume that it’s doing this for every single one of the extra files, however, I’m not too sure. I’ve been looking everywhere for help on this - so some help here would be much appreciated! Thank you :)

Comment: This most likely means the windows SDK is not installed or you have the wrong one selected in your project settings. There are several duplicates of this with a similar 400 or so errors.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489899/over-400-errors-when-using-visual-studio-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489899/over-400-errors-when-using-visual-studio-c)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you couldn't install or use the windows SDK correctly. I suggest you could try to reinstall the windows sdk. Open the VS Installer window, you could click on "Individual Components", then scroll quite a ways down to get to the "SDKs, libraries and frameworks" section. In there, you could choose download and install the SDK which you want.

[image]

And then right click the project-> Properties -> General -> Windows SDK Version to set the Windows SDK.

[image]

Comment: @user15891345 Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us.