# Visual Studio can't open c++ system headers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, configuration, header-files, visual-studio-2022

I just created an MFC app project in Visual Studio 2022 and when I just created it without any of my code, I ran it and got an error:

```
The system cannot find the file specified
```

The I found many of the header files are not in the header file directory:

[image]

Since I have not coded anything yet, I think that it could be an installing problem (e.g. I miss the installing of some specific components) so I checked the installed components:

[image]

I also tried to find the header file in the error list by right click on, for example "#include <float.h>" and select "Go To Document <float.h>", then there's an error

```
file "float.h" not found in current source file's directory in build system paths.
```

It seems like that the C++ header files are not installed or configured at all so that I cannot use them. I'm using the version of visual studio 2022 in a windows x64 laptop. Can anyone help me with the problem?

Comment: reinstall C++ in your visual studio

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him  which part should I reinstall? the "desktop development with C++" or some individual components?

Comment: nah, the complete c++ modules.

Comment: I believe this means the Windows SDK you have selected in your project settings is no longer installed on your PC. There are many such questions like this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489899/over-400-errors-when-using-visual-studio-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489899/over-400-errors-when-using-visual-studio-c)

Comment: Also: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67479106/visual-studio-isn-t-running-a-hello-world-script-even-the-one-that-it-included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67479106/visual-studio-isn-t-running-a-hello-world-script-even-the-one-that-it-included)

Comment: @drescherjm  Thanks aloooooot! it is the problem of the SDK. The errors disappeared after I reinstalled the SDK!

Comment: @drescherjm  yes it does.