# Just installed visual studio; 478 of "E0282 the global scope has no..." errors when compiling C++ program

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I'm trying to run a program that prints out "hello" just to see if I can get C++ to run on my machine (running Windows 10 Home and Visual Studio 17.0.5).  When I compile the program, I get all kinds of errors that seem to point to files that I haven't even included in my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "hello";
    return 0;
}
```

[screenshot of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRAG9.png)

Comment: This means your SDK setting is wrong. In your project settings make sure that the selected windows SDK is installed.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489899/over-400-errors-when-using-visual-studio-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489899/over-400-errors-when-using-visual-studio-c)

Comment: May I know if your problem has been solved. Did the C++ workload install correctly? Try to repair VS.

Comment: That fixed it!  Just needed to modify the app to include SDK.  Thank you!