# visual studio error e1696 -"cannot open source file iostream"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

When I build a cmake project in visual studio and this error occurs, I tried to uninstall and reinstall visual studio but it did not work.
the Build succeeded and the program ran but in error list I got the error "cannot open source file "iostream"".
I use the visual studio 2022 program.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK50Y.png)

Comment: Instead of uninstalling the entire compiler, have you tried a simple Visual Studio C++ console project, with a simple "Hello World" program, and **not** use CMake to do this?  If that works correctly, don't waste time and resources uninstalling and installing the compiler suite.  The issue is CMake, not Visual Studio.

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve] with minimal `CMakeLists.txt` and C++ source file. There are many things which might go wrong... I'm using CMake with VS for several years and never faced any issues with just standard C++ projects. (I cannot remember that I had to prepare anything special just for CMake/VS/C++ - just install everything, make a solution file with CMake GUI, open it in VS, and compile.)

Comment: Since VS2019 (or even VS2017?), there is an option to load `CMakeLists.txt` directly in VS (instead of a solution file). I once tried it out-of-curiosity but the result was confusing to me. Hence, I dropped this and am using the "old" workflow (via CMake GUI and solution file) which still does the job fine.

Comment: I tried to open a new project without Cmake and run it and it worked without errors, what could be the problem with Cmake?

Comment: It could be problem with the project you are trying to build, it could be wrong settings of CMake or Visual Studio. Your post contains so little information, so it is impossible to suggest something more specific. Please, (re-)read [ask] and edit the question post accordingly.

Comment: If you get 400+ errors the problem is most likely that the windows SDK version selected in your project settings is not installed. There are many questions like that: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489899/over-400-errors-when-using-visual-studio-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489899/over-400-errors-when-using-visual-studio-c)

Comment: If you have a valid SDK installed and configure with CMake it should update your project file to use the new SDK version.